# Inverse compare to maybe null value in sql

Tags: sql, null, isnull

if i compare a value to a maybe-null value is found this solution:

```
field = ? OR (x IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)
```

what would be the negation of this expression, when i want my field not to be the same as "?" ?

Comment: `not (field = ? OR (x IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))`

Comment: tough idea... sorry for the stupid question =)

Comment: Or this: `field <> ? AND (x IS NOT NULL OR ? IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: do you mean `field is distinct from ?`